# Identify all approved documents and pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, workflow, 2016

I am looking at identifying all documents that have been approved. Our documents are bound to a content type

One way to do this would be to copy some reference to a document in a generic list

This list can then be list a master list. However i am hoping to do this using a 2010 globally reusable workflow if possible

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is out of the box Search an option? You could set up a search result source looking for ContentType:'Your Content Type' ( and perhaps limit the scope to either this site, this site collection or a specific site/site collection

Comment: Hi Kasper due to delays in crawling generally we  did not keep. Search as an option, workflows or an API call is where we are thinking. A workflow could copy a reference to a global list which we can query and find out what. Has been approved/updated

Comment: If the delay is significant from the business point of view and you don't mind adding additional code and cost, then the workflow solution sounds right. However many managers can accept a 15 min delay if the additional cost is more than e.g. 5000 USD over 3 years ;-)